# Discord.js doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My code worked fine but I changed some things and now it doesn't...

When I type `!ping` in the any channel it doesn't work.

- the bot is on the server and an admin.
- I changed the token down there
- here's the code: Does anyone see something??

```js
const Discord = require(`discord.js`),
client = new Discord.Client(),
prefix = `!`,

NO    = `801418578069815297`
YES   = `801418578300764180`

client.login(`bruh`)

client.once(`ready`, () => {
  console.log(`online.`)
  client.user.setPresence({
      status: `online`,
      game: {
          name: `You`,
          type: `WATCHING`
      }
  })
})
client.on(`message`, message =>{                                                
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.client) return        
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(` `)         
    const arg = args.toString().split(sep)                                      
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()
      if(command === `ping`){                                                     
          message.channel.send(`pong!`)                                           
      }
      }
    )
```

EDIT:

I put some log outputs in:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
let client = new Discord.Client();
let prefix = "!";
console.log("discord, client, prefix defined.")

client.login("bruh");
console.log("logged in.")
client.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("online.");
  client.user.setPresence({
      status: "online",
      game: {
          name: "You",
          type: "WATCHING"
      }
  });
});

client.on("message", message =>{                                                
  console.log("message recieved")  
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.client) return;
  console.log("it's a command.")
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
    console.log("splitted.")        
    const arg = args.toString().split(sep);    
    console.log("args defined.")                               
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    console.log("command defined.")

    if(command === "ping") {      
      console.log("command identified:"+command)                                               
        message.channel.send("pong!");
        console.log("message sent.")                                           
    }
});
```

The output is:

```
logged in.
online.
message recieved
```

I looked at that closely but still didn't find anything...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to make it work. contact me on discord Moderpo#0172 if you wanna know the answer I'll have to find out what I did because I forgot lol

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, you're using commas where you should be using semicolons, so JS will be interepreting this strangely which will give you undefined behaviour. You should also preferably prefix your variables with `let`, `var` or `const` otherwise this could also lead to undefined behaviour. It is recommended to use `let` over `var`.

Try the code below to fix your problem:

```js
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
let client = new Discord.Client();
let prefix = '!';

let NO = "801418578069815297";
let YES = "801418578300764180";

client.login(`bruh`);

client.once(`ready`, () => {
  console.log(`online.`);
  client.user.setPresence({
      status: `online`,
      game: {
          name: `You`,
          type: `WATCHING`
      }
  });
});

client.on(`message`, message =>{                                                
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.client) return;
     
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === `ping`) {                                                     
        message.channel.send(`pong!`);                                           
    }
});
```

Comment: Recommended to use `const` or `let` over `var`

Comment: That didn't work for me... I put the token in, I saved the file and I checked the package.json: "main": "pingtest.js" still doesn't work. But thank you for looking at it so closely and spending your time on trying to help me!

Comment: I also changed the quotation marks, that didn't help

Comment: I have updated my code, please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems in the past with using wrong quotation marks, that might be the case for you here as well

Try to replace all your ` with ' or "

Comment: using different methods of string initialization shouldn't make a difference, unless string format errors are occurring such as incorrect markdown

Comment: Someone told me that I should use those ` but ig ' should work as it's featured in many tutorial pages. Imma try that.


-Ok I tried but it didn't change anything.